# Show that the following space is not Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $S= \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2:x=0 \ \text{or} \ y=0 \}$. Let $\mathcal{T}$ be the topology on $ \mathbb{R}^2$ and define $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to S$ by $f(0,y)=(0,y)$ and $f(x,y)=(x,0)$ if $x \neq 0$. Let $\mathcal{U}$ the quotient topology on $S$ induced by $f$. Show that $(S, \mathcal{U})$ is not Hausdorff.
I supose that I have to find two points $(a,b), (x,y) \in S$ with $(a,b) \neq (x,y)$ such that for every open set $U,V$ in $S$ with $(a,b) \in U$ and $(x,y) \in V$ and $U \cap V = \emptyset$, but I tried a lot of times and I didn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Show that if $y_0\ne y_1$, then $f(0,y_0)$ and $f(0,y_1)$ do not have disjoint open nbhds in $S$.

Comment: If $(0,y_0) \neq (0,y_1)$ and I suposse that $S$ is Hausdorff then exists $U,V$ open in $S$ such that $(0,y_0) \in U$ and $(0,y_1) \in V$ with $U \cap V = \emptyset$ so $f(0,y_0)=(0,y_0) \in U$ then $(0,y_0) \in f^{-1} (U)$ and also $(0,y_1) \in f^{-1} (V)$ but $f$ is a quotient map so $f^{-1} (U)$ and $f^{-1} (V) $ are open in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and what can I do?

Comment: @erika21148: You need to think about what open sets in $S$ look like. Here’s another hint: no matter what $y$ is, every open nbhd of $f(0,y)$ contains a set of the form $(-\epsilon,0)\cup(0,\epsilon)$.